# Mac address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff in C (hex)

Tags: hex, mac-address, arrays

How do I write the MAC address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff as a char[] in C?

Do I just do `char macaddress[6] = "%0xFF%0xFF%0xFF%0xFF%0xFF%0xFF";`

I'm not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char macaddress[6] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
```

Comment: doesn't `char macaddress[6] = {0xff};` initialize all the items to `0xff`?

Comment: No, that initializes to { 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }.

Answer (score 1):

I rather do like this `char macaddress[] = "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff";`

There is some coding guide lines for char array initializations, because need to be null-terminated and the size is actually 7.

> Do not initialize an array of
>   characters using a string literal with
>   more characters (including the '\0')
>   than the array. Therefore, it is
>   necessary to specify the correct size
>   of  a string literal (char s[4] =
>   "abc";).
>   However, because the result
>   of the expectation always can be
>   obtained even if the size of the
>   string literal is changed, the method
>   of not describing the size (char s[] =
>   "abc";) is  recommended.

ref:
http://www.caravan.net/ec2plus/guide.html